# How to use argument with dash in name in ffmpeg-python?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-encoding, ffmpeg-python

Following is a simple ffmpeg command line for encoding an input video into a AV1 output with CRF 30:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libsvtav1 -crf 30 output.mkv
```

Converting that command line into the syntax of [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) is pretty straight-forward:

```py
(
    ffmpeg
    .input('input.mkv')
    .output('output.mkv', vcodec='libsvtav1', crf=30)
    .run()
)
```

However, what happens if we want to specify the fast-decode option? In ffmpeg that would mean extending our command line to include `-svtav1-params fast-decode=1`, i.e.:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libsvtav1 -crf 30 -svtav1-params fast-decode=1 output.mkv
```

How do we specify the same thing in ffmpeg-python? Adding `svtav1-params='fast-decode=1'` into the output arguments results in invalid Python code since variables are not allowed to have dash in the name:

```py
(
    ffmpeg
    .input('input.mkv')
    .output('output.mkv', vcodec='libsvtav1', crf=30, svtav1-params='fast-decode=1')
    .run()
)
# Error: Expected parameter name
```

Replacing the dash with an underscore in the name makes ffmpeg-python read it literally which doesn't translate into a valid ffmpeg command line.

How is it possible to specify fast-decode and other `svtav1-params` specific arguments in ffmpeg-python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation,
you can use the `**` syntax to pass additional arguments for **Special option names** like this

```bash
(
    ffmpeg
    .input('input.mkv')
    .output('output.mkv', vcodec='libsvtav1', crf=30, **{'svtav1-params': 'fast-decode=1'})
    .run()
)
```